# Having trouble reversing an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, reverse

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse(int *, int);

int main()
{
    const int len = 10;
    int intArray[len] = {5, 6, 4, 1, 3, 10, 15, 13, 2, 7};
    reverse(intArray, len);
}

void reverse(int intArray[], int len)
{
    int j = len;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        --j;
        intArray[i] = intArray[j];
        cout << intArray[i] << " ";

    }
}
```

Then here is my output:

```
7 2 13 15 10 10 15 13 2 7
```

I see some examples of code doing the same thing, and I want to know why they all use a temp variable and if it is necessary?

Also, this question is a variation of an assignment MIT OCW. Though their assignment does not require the reversed array to be printed out, they want us to store the reversed values in the original array. But for some reason, their for loop only runs half the length? Here is their solution:

```
void reverse (int numbers [] , const int numbersLen ) 
{

for(int i = 0; i < numbersLen / 2; ++ i ) {

int tmp = numbers [ i ];

int indexFromEnd = numbersLen - i - 1;

numbers [ i ] = numbers [ indexFromEnd ];

numbers [ indexFromEnd ] = tmp ;

}

}
```

Comment: First try changing the loop condition to `i < len / 2` and see what happens.

Comment: I get this:

    7 2 13 15 10

which is correct but I already know that from my initial output: only half my output is correct.

Comment: Also try printing it *after* the `reverse` call in the `main` function. The reason I tell you this is because right now you are swapping place of everything *twice*. (I suggest you step through the code line by line using a debugger to see it.)

Comment: Their solution is correct: by swapping each pair of opposite int, you only need to go to half the length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save all the "reversed" bytes into the same array overwriting original elements. Use another, empty array to save the result to.

If you need to use the same array, you would swap corresponding elements. For swapping you need the temporary variable and run the loop only half the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the standard algorithm `std::reverse` with the `std::begin` and `std::end` iterators

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int len = 10;
    int intArray[len] = {5, 6, 4, 1, 3, 10, 15, 13, 2, 7};
    std::reverse(std::begin(intArray), std::end(intArray));

    for (auto&& e : intArray)
        std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f665784f87b7aef9).

If you have to write your own reverse algorithm, here's a possible implementation

```
template<class BidirIt>
void reverse(BidirIt first, BidirIt last)
{
    while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
        std::iter_swap(first++, last);
    }
}
```

Here, `std::iter_swap(a, b)` just calls `std::swap(*a, *b)`. You can come up with your own swap of course.

It's recommended to have algorithms take iterator pairs so as to be compatible with the rest of the Standard Library.

Comment: This is clearly a homework assignment where the point is to implement the reversal algorithm, using `std::reverse` kind of misses the point...

Comment: @MatteoItalia one of the points is to try and write algorithms in STL style

Answer (score 1):

Use the following for loop in the reverse function:

```
int tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
{
    --j;
    tmp = intArray[j];
    intArray[j] = intArray[i];
    intArray[i] = tmp;
}
```

then print the array from a different loop.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, trying manual reverse algorithm and output in a single loop.

```
void reverse(int intArray[], int len)
{
    if (len <= 0)
        return;
    cout << intArray[len - 1] << " ";
    if (len == 1)
        return;
    reverse(intArray + 1, len - 2);
    int tmp = intArray[0];
    cout << tmp << " ";
    intArray[0] = intArray[len - 1];
    intArray[len - 1] = tmp;
}
```

The tmp variable is necessary for a swap of two values. Otherwise, on first assignment (=) you would lose some data.